# Sql query where condition and or

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have the following data in my table:

id: 1, name: TOM, visible: 1, field_1: EMPTY, field_2: EMPTY, field_3: EMPTY.

```
SELECT id, name FROM table 
WHERE name <> 'TOM' AND visible = 1 
      AND field_1 <> '' OR field_2 <> '' OR field_3 <> ''
```

I want to select only the rows where name is different than 'name1' and at least one of the fields is not empty.

I expected no results for this query but i get: id, TOM like the where name condition is overwritten.

Comment: Define "empty". Do you mean null, blank or literally the text "EMPTY"?

Comment: Can you provide sqlfiddle with your data

Comment: blank field, field_1 2 and 3 are varchars. pardon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, that one of the field is really != '', making the condition valid for "Tom" record. You must group OR conditions, using brackets:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table 
WHERE name <> 'TOM' AND visible = 1 
      AND (field_1 <> '' OR field_2 <> '' OR field_3 <> '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is precedence: bracket the ORs:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table 
WHERE name <> 'TOM'
AND visible = 1 
AND (field_1 <> '' OR field_2 <> '' OR field_3 <> '')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `and` operator has a higher precedence than `or` (see [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) for extra details), so if we take your query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table 
WHERE name <> 'TOM' AND visible = 1 
      AND field_1 <> '' OR field_2 <> '' OR field_3 <> ''
```

And add clarifying parentheses, we'll get:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table 
WHERE (name <> 'TOM' AND visible = 1 AND field_1 <> '') 
      OR field_2 <> '' 
      OR field_3 <> ''
```

Which is not what you wanted. You can solve this by explicitly adding parentheses:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM   table 
WHERE  name <> 'TOM' AND 
       visible = 1 AND
       (field_1 <> '' OR field_2 <> '' OR field_3 <> '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add ()

```
SELECT id, name
FROM    table 
WHERE name <> 'TOM'
AND visible = 1 
AND (field_1 <> ''OR field_2 <> '' OR field_3 <> '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please enclose empty fields comparison in one paranthesis block as show in bold
SELECT id, name FROM table 
WHERE name <> 'TOM' AND visible = 1 
      AND  **(**  field_1 <> '' OR field_2 <> '' OR field_3 <> ''  )

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to insert brackets
2. Are the empty fields really empty? Maybe the '' doesn't bring the right results